# Is there a way to send filter object like prop in ReferenceField so that I can catch it in dataprovider in params?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to send filter object using ReferenceField, so that I can get that object on dataprovider in params so that I can put filter when doing GET_MANY call to the API.

Similar thing exist in ReferenceManyField and that works just fine but, there you send multiple calls to the API unlike in ReferenceField where you send just group of ids and that's it.

For example simple GET_MANY is something like this:

**https:\somewebsite.com\api\v1\users?filter[id_in]='123adb'**

Now I would like to send some filter and do something like this:

**https:\somewebsite.com\api\v1\cars?filter[user_id_in]='123adb'**

This part with filter I would like to dynamically get it from params in dataprovider and then create https request according to that.

I can do something like checking what resource it is and then based of that create the right URL for API request but that doesn't seems to me like a good solution, because that would make dataprovider look dirty with all the IF's.

```
<ReferenceField
label="Car name"
source="id"
reference="cars"
filter:{{user_id_in: "user_id_in"}}
> 
<TextField source="name"/>

</ReferenceField>
```

This is what I would like to do, but I know that ReferenceField doesn't have filter prop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the Data Provider, you can do the required operations in the decorator: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload.

Here is an example decorator for modifying the date format in queries:

```
addUploadCapabilities.js

const addUploadCapabilities = (requestHandler, apiUrl) => (type, resource, params) => {
  if ((type === 'GET_LIST') && (Object.keys(params.filter).length)) {     
    const { filter, ...otherParams } = params

    const newFilter = Object.entries(filter).reduce((result, [name, value]) => {
      if (value && value.hasOwnProperty('lte')) {
        let maxValue = value.lte

        const regexp = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/
        let match = regexp.exec(value.lte) // Only for dates
        if (match) {
            maxValue = `${match[1]}-${match[2]}-${match[3]}T23:59:59.999Z`
        }

        if (value.hasOwnProperty('gte')) {
          result[name] = { between: [value.gte, maxValue] } // Replace the conditions lte + gte with between
        } else {
          result[name] = { lte: maxValue } // Shift the end date to the end of the day
        }
      } else {
        result[name] = value // Other values are copied to the new filter
      }

      return result
    }, {})

    return requestHandler(type, resource, { ...otherParams, filter: newFilter }) 
  }
}
export default addUploadCapabilities
```

Comment: I have read that, but that's just IF conditional outside the dataprovider. You get here type resource and params, and based on type and resource you make the correct url, in params there isn't a way to get filter.

Correct me if I am wrong, and maybe you can provide example of implementing that decorator ?

Comment: You are absolutely right in your conclusions, but this is the best solution that I found to coordinate my requests with the server API.

Comment: That's cool implementation but that's for GET_LIST and if I am not mistaken you can pass filter for GET_LIST in LIST Component and than you can use that filter in dataprovider and dataprovider decorator as well. 
But for GET_MANY I think I can't do it in that way. That's the main issue for me. I can do like IF(resource==="cars") return {url: https:\\somewebsite.com\api\cars?filter[user_id_in] } and do it like that for all other cases. But somehow that doesn't look to me as best solution.